# Laravel Validation, a field should be 1 if another field is 0 and viceversa

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

suppose, i have a request object which sends

```
[
 a => 0,
 b => 0
]
```

I want to have a validation, which will result to an error as both a and b are 0. I need at least one to be 1. how can I do that?
Another working eg:

```
[
 a => 0,
 b => 1
]
```

it should pass

Comment: you can use `required_without` if you change your `0` to  "nothing"

Comment: yes I couldn't do that atleast 0 is expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the custom rules for this too particular case.

```php
$request->validate([
    'a' => [
        'integer',
        'between:0,1',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            if (!$value && !$request->b) {
                $fail($attribute.' is invalid.'); //you can customize the message here
            }
        }
    ],
    'b' => 'integer|between:0,1'
]);
```

The rule can be only on one, so the user doesnt get 2 error messages.

Comment: Good answer, but I would pass in the fields that should be at least 1 true and use an bitwise-OR operator on all of them to have a minimalistic piece of validation that is reusable.

Comment: I am getting an error on $this->b undefined property although I have `b` on request

Comment: @onlineThomas why am I getting $this->b is undefined property. although is is on the request object

Comment: @ReyYoung my bad, was using `FormRequest` syntax.

Comment: Can this be done in nested arrays ?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth of course, it's just a validation rule, nothing related to the field format being validated. use `input.*`

Comment: Yes I do know about input.*.variable but how about inside the if statement? I cannot use $request->input.*.variable or $request['input.*.variable] if array

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth are you sending a double set of arrays? You should post a question about your special case so you can provide more details at once.

Answer (score 1):

There's a validation rule called 'different'.
Suppose you could use it like this

```
$request->validate([
   'a' => 'different:b',
   'b' => 'different:a'
]);
```

You can combine these with integer and between rule:

```
$request->validate([
   'a' => 'integer|between:0,1|different:b',
   'b' => 'integer|between:0,1|different:a'
]);
```

I haven't tried this, but you can read about it in the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-different

Comment: I think in the case a =1 and b = 1, it should still be valid.

Comment: as @N69S said it wouldn't work for the case of 1 & 1

Comment: @N69S why would it still be valid? It works for me [here](https://implode.io/r5aPq1)

Comment: It should be valid to have `a == 1 and b == 1`, but in your answer the validator would return an error.

Comment: True, my case would state that the 2 parameters cannot have the same value.