# Laravel validation for nested array request where if one of the integer is zero, the other should be more than zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I need to validate a laravel request like in this accepted answer in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819371/13933721). However my request is a nested array. What my current code based on the answer:

```
    $rules = [
        'nested_array.*.variable_a' => [
            'integer',
            'between:0,1',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {
                if (!$value && !$request['variable_b']) {
                    $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.'); //you can customize the message here
                }
            }
        ],
        'nested_array.*.variable_b' => 'integer|between:0,1',
        'nested_array.*.order' => ['required', 'integer'],
    ];
```

I am unable to use `!$request['variable_b']` nor `!$request['nested_array.*.variable_b']` returning `Undefined array key`. Will need to change the `between:0,1` rule later but the main concern is to validate nested array.

If you have a different way for my question, that would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply back the logic a bit

```
$rules = [
        'nested_array.*.variable_a' =>  'integer|between:0,1',
        'nested_array.*.variable_b' => 'integer|between:0,1',
        'nested_array.*.order' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'nested_array.*' => [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {
                if (!$value['variable_a'] && !$value['variable_b']) {
                    $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.'); //you can customize the message here
                }
            }
        ],
    ];
```

You can also add the existence of the variable in the condition too

```
$rules = [
        'nested_array.*.variable_a' =>  'integer|between:0,1',
        'nested_array.*.variable_b' => 'integer|between:0,1',
        'nested_array.*.order' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'nested_array.*' => [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {
                if ((!isset($value['variable_a']) || !$value['variable_a']) && (!isset($value['variable_b']) || !$value['variable_b'])) {
                    $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.'); //you can customize the message here
                }
            }
        ],
    ];
```