# How to access specific current iteration nested value in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
Validator::make([
    'tagDetails' => ['required', 'array'],
    'tagDetails.*.tagId' => ['distinct'],
    'tagDetails.*.name' => [
        'distinct',
        'required_without:tagDetails.*.tagId',
        Rule::unique('tag_masters', 'name')
        ->ignore(
           ( !empty( //want to access current iteration tagId Value ))
        ),
    ]
])
```

Request:

```
{
    name: "test",
    tagDetails: [
        {
            "tagId": "123"
            "name" : "Tag1",
            "hexColorCode" : "#FF1931"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "4556",
            "name" : "Tag2",
            "hexColorCode" : "#FF1931"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have implement validation, want to ignore current database tagName that is linked with tagId

```
Validator::make([
    'tagDetails' => ['required', 'array'],
    'tagDetails.*.tagId' => ['distinct'],
    'tagDetails.*.name' => [
        'distinct',
        'required_without: tagDetails.*.tagId',
        Rule::unique('tag_masters', 'name')
            ->ignore(
               (!empty($this->tagDetails.*.tagId))
            ),
    ]
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Validation, a field should be 1 if another field is 0 and viceversa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819010/laravel-validation-a-field-should-be-1-if-another-field-is-0-and-viceversa)

Comment: You can't use the `*` wildcard if you're wanting to compare this input at a specific index with another input at the same index. You need to construct your rules as `tagDetails.0.name`, then check `$this->tagDetails[0]->name` (or `$this->tagDetails[0]['name']`,  `$this['tagDetails'][0]['name']`, whichever works), and the same for the other indices, like `tagDetails.1.name`, `tagDetails.2.name`, and so on.

Comment: @TimLewis can you suggest me an example of doing that

Comment: Loop over your input and create the rules that require specific index checks. `$rules = ['tagDetails' => ['required', 'array'], 'tagDetails.*.tagId' => ['distinct']];`, then `foreach($request->input('tagDetails', []) as $index => $tagDetails) { $rules["tagDetails.{$index}.name"] = ['distinct', "required_without:tagDetails.{$index}.tagId", Rule::unique('tag_masters', 'name')->ignore($tagDetails->tagId)]; }` (or similar; you'll need to try it and debug any issues).